# how to pass rake task to run on old environment from new env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake-task

my tool is working on rails 3 , but I have old application are running on 2.1.1 (rails 2.1.1 and ruby 1.8.6) and so many libraries are running on old environment(rails 2.1.1 and ruby 1.8.6). I have to send request from new env to old env to generate report . what is best way to approach this scenario? or how to pass rake task to run on old environment from new env?

the report is under lib/abc.rb (on old environment(rails 2.1.1 and ruby 1.8.6)) call this library and dump the yaml into db from new environment (rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Does your Rails 2 application use Bundler? If so, try using

```
bundle exec <your command>
```

Ex:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

But standard way is to use rvm (http://beginrescueend.com/) to handle multiple ruby versions and get versions. You can do it easily via '`getsets`'.

The following is a quick note I wrote on managing multiple Ruby/gems:

http://keepthingssimple.tumblr.com/post/11274588229/using-rvm-to-keep-things-simple